# How to draw stream lines of water impinging against an obstacle

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, tikz-styles

### Motivation

I'm taking a fluid mechanics course and I'm creating slides that contain images of real-life examples of fluids. I would draw stream lines of water impinging against an obstacle (for example a cube), but I have problem to do that.

### Question

Not knowing how to represent it, I initially asked ChatGPT if it could give me a code that would represent it but after several attempts (I swear I tried to make him do it at least 20 times but he created a series of meaningless drawings) this is the best it was able to give me (next to what I asked it to draw):

[image]  [image]

The 4 mistakes I can't get it to fix are:

1. The fact that I don't want two separate vectors, but a solid line with more "^"
2. Lines must not pass through the obstacle
3. The lines must not be parallel but must thicken upwards to indicate a greater flow of water and must dissipate before and after the obstacle
4. I can't get it to generate vortices

Could someone please help me?

> As an answer I would also accept another AI (possibly free) capable of generating this kind of codes (just so I don't bother you here)

I leave the code generated by ChatGPT:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[gray!40] (2,0) rectangle (6,5);

\foreach \y in {0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5} {
    \draw[->] (0,\y) .. controls (2,\y+0.8) and (4,\y+1.2) .. (6,\y);
    \draw[->] (6,\y) .. controls (7,\y+0.2) and (7.5,\y-0.2) .. (8,\y);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome. Shouldn't a fluid dynamics course be able to tell you how the curves and spirals look like, mathematically, in relation to the obstacle?

Comment: Do you need a physically correct representation (whatever that might be) or just schematic? Because the latter would probably not be too difficult: it is just a few curved lines with some arrow-head decoration ...

Comment: As a general rule you should try your own mental skill rather than some AI, which still hardly exceeds the toddler level ... Here's a good entry-point: https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

- introduce some coordinates into your manual sketch
- do a 1st very rough drawing
- introduce some refinement as 2nd step

From your drawing:

[image: sketch]

1st and 2nd results:

[image: results]

Code:

- the decoration is copied from a previous solution, so it may be a bit overdone or unbalanced
- you'll get the idea
- straight lines are replaced by bent lines, using `out` and `in` angles

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
 % === 1st sketch from your manual drawing ===
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,3.5) {1st sketch};
    \draw[help lines] (-3,0) grid (3,3);;
    % ~~~ box ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (-1,0) rectangle (1,1.7); 
    
    % ~~~ flow lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (-3,3) -- (3,3);                  % A
    \draw (-3,2.5) -- (0,2.8) -- (3,2.5);   % B
    \draw (-3,1.8) -- (0,2.5) -- (3,1.8);   % C
    \draw (-3,.7) -- (0,2) -- (3,.7);       % D
    
    % ~~~ vortices ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw (-2.8, 0) -- (-1.5,.6) -- (-1.8, 1) -- (-1.8,.5);
    \draw (-1.5, 0) -- (-1.3,.4) -- (-1.5,.5) -- (-1.4,.4);
    \draw (1.5,1.1) -- ( 1.8,.5) -- ( 1.3,.3) -- ( 1.5,.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}


 % ~~~ 2nd: refinements ~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    [decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0.06 and .5 step 5.3mm with {\arrow{stealth}} ,
        mark=between positions 0.6 and .8 step 6mm with {\arrow{stealth}} ,
        mark=between positions 0.835 and 1 step 6mm with {\arrow{stealth}}
    }]
    \draw[help lines] (-3,0) grid (3,3);
    \node at (0,3.5) {2nd: refinements};
    % ~~~ box ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (-1,0) rectangle (1,1.7);
    
    % ~~~ flow lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-3,3) -- (3,3);                   % A
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-3,2.5) to[out=7,in=180] 
                                 ( 0,2.8) to[out=0,in=173] (3,2.5); % B
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-3,1.8) to[out=15,in=180] 
                                 ( 0,2.5) to[out=0,in=165] (3,1.8); % C
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-3,.7) to[out=20,in=180] 
                                 ( 0,2) to[out=0,in=160] (3,.7);    % D
    
    % ~~~ vortices ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-2.8, 0) to[out=20,in=220] 
                                 (-1.5,.6) to[out=60,in=50] 
                                 (-1.8, 1) to[out=230,in=210] (-1.8,.5);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-2.1, 0) to[out=10,in=0]
                                 (-1.3,.4)  -- (-1.4,.4);
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (1.5,1.1) to[out=-40,in=90]
                                 ( 1.8,.5) to[out=270,in=-65] 
                                 ( 1.3,.3) to[out=115,in=100] ( 1.5,.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
%  to[out=,in=]

 % ~~~ drawn by Artificial Incompetence ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (4,6.5) {coded via Artificial Incompetence:};
    \filldraw[gray!40] (2,0) rectangle (6,5);
    
    \foreach \y in {0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5} {
        \draw[->] (0,\y) .. controls (2,\y+0.8) and (4,\y+1.2) .. (6,\y);
        \draw[->] (6,\y) .. controls (7,\y+0.2) and (7.5,\y-0.2) .. (8,\y);
}

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```